# Recognising nearby iPhones running my app

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, detection

I have a requirement in my iPhone app that I know when somebody running the same app is close by.
I'm thinking that GameKit using Bluetooth would let me do that. GPS location is not precise enough in this particular case.

However, if the user closes the app then the function won't work anymore. Even under iOS4, the task switching will close down the BonJour services so I can't have the app run in the background.

Seems to me I can only have this function if the user leaves the app up and running. Would you agree? Or is there a different approach I can take?

Comment: That about sums it up if you ask me

Answer (score 0):

People are very concerned with privacy, so they would naturally expect such privacy invading functionality to be switched off when they close down the application.

If they choose to have this feature enabled, then it's a different matter. Then they expect that somebody else may locate them.

You might however consider implementing some sort of opt-in offline service, where the latest gps position is stored on a server including a timestamp. When somebody else (with the app running) moves within a certain distance of this location while it's still "fresh", then you send off a notification to the first device. That way the user would be notified that somebody may be close, and can then switch on their own device.

Comment: Yes am aware of the privacy issues and agree. This is more the technical side of things. I'm only talking a smallish area inside a building, e.g. a nightclub or similar sort of venue. Lots of bodies that want to meet. A user would mark a list of people they want to meet. When they are close by they would be notified. In this case GPS won't be precise enough. With Bluetooth, the two devices would connect silently, determine if they are compatible and only then notify the user.

Looks like the app will need to be left running all the time. Not sure how the battery will last!